# Cancel an async FindIterable in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, project-reactor

I have a query in mongodb that return a lot of results.  I encapsulate the FindIterable into a reactive Flowable and stream the result using spring-boot-webflux.

When the user disconnect, I receive the cancel event in the Flowable but, I don't find a way to stop the mongo iteration.

I create the Flowable like that :

private static Flowable toFlowable(FindIterable cursor){

```
    return Flowable.create(emitter -> {

        cursor
            .forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(Document doc) {
                    log.debug("Next Block :" + doc.toJson());
                    emitter.onNext(doc);                    
                }
            } , new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Void result, Throwable t) {
                    log.debug("Completed");
                    emitter.onComplete();
                }
            });         
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
}
```

and I create the query that way :

```
public Flowable<SomeType> find(String value){

    Bson filter = Filters.eq("key", value);
    FindIterable<Document> iterable =  collection.find(filter);

    return toFlowable(iterable)
            .map(doc -> adapter.convert(doc))
            .doOnCancel(() -> {
                log.info("Cancel Flowable");
                **--> iterable.stop????**
            });
```

I am using the  'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.6.3'.

Is there a way to stop the async iterable in mongo?